# C++ ran into design issue from solving circular dependency

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm coming from JAVA background, so following situation is giving me a problem.

Class A.h

```
class B;
Class A{
  public:
  B* bInstance;

}
```

and another class B.h

```
#include "A.h"
Class B{
   public:
    A instanceA;
    B(A& a);
    void foo();
}
```

The thing is, now it turns out that I cannot use foo method of class B from class A. How do I deal with this? Is this due to a bad design decision?

My reasoning behind this decision was to implement different children classes of B, who will be changing members of class A in different manners for the same parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include `B.h` in `A.cpp`. Then you can call methods of B.

Comment: Ahhh. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. In the *A.cpp* file.